# Parent-child routes in React-Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router to route between components in in my app. How do I create a route for a landing page outside the app itself? Ie., the user lands on the page and the LandingPage routes to the app, then the app can route the components/views in the navbar accordingly.

The problem i'm running into is that the Navbar keeps populating in the landing page as well.

Here are the routes:

```
// React
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");
var Route = Router.Route;
var NotFoundRoute = Router.NotFoundRoute;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;

var App = require('./components/App.js');
var About = require('./components/About.js');
var Concat = require('./components/Concat.js');
var Home = require('./components/Home.js');
var Landing = require('./components/Landing.js');
var Login = require('./components/Login.js');
var Search = require('./components/Search');
var Signup = require('./components/Signup');

var routes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Landing} />
    <Route name="about" handler={About}/>
    <Route name="concat" handler={Concat}/>
    <Route name="home" handler={Home}/>
    <Route name="login" handler={Login}/>
    <Route name="search" handler={Search}/> 
    <Route name="signup" handler={Signup}/>       
  </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

This is App.js

```
var React  = require('react');
var Navbar = require('./Navbar.js');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Landing = require('./Landing.js');

var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Navbar />
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

This is the Navbar:

```
var React  = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Link = Router.Link;

var Navbar = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span className="icon-bar">test</span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
              <li className="active"><Link to="home">Jobletics</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="concat">Create a Listing</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="search">Search Jobs</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><Link to="login">Log in</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="signup">Sign up</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Navbar;
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would check if and see if the current route is the landing route and then hide the navigation bar accordingly. You could also restructure your routes or the html in your components but if only one route is the exception I would go with just checking if the current route is landing or not.

Comment: can you please calrify with a code snippet or a source to view

Answer (score 0):

You can try link this ..

```
  <BrowserRouter  >
                 <Route push={true} path="/users/activation/:atoken" component={Activation}/> 
  </BrowserRouter>
```